# Access ASPX elements inside classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bunch of methods which manipulate the ASPX page elements and at this point it makes sense to encapsulate them into their own static object. However, it seems like I do not have access into the form elements outside of the ASPX page. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Why a static object?  Does it truly have no state?  Also, is this something you want to just have a base class for so you can inherit the functionality in child classes?  Finally, if it is manipulating aspx page elements does it make more sense to create a web user control with the elements and encapsulated functionality?  In short, can you give an actual example of what you have and what you want?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I do not have access into the form elements outside of the ASPX page." Do you mean you're using FindControl and it doesn't return anything? Please post a code sample to explain what you are doing, and explain the error a little more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the Page itself into the class, see the example below:

**ASPX page**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Text="Test" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = new Process(this);
        string s = p.GetTextBoxValue();
    }
```

**Class**

```
    public class Process
    {
        public Page thePage { get; set; }

        public Process(Page page)
        {
            thePage = page;
        }

        public string GetTextBoxValue()
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)thePage.FindControl("txtTest");
            return tb.Text;
        }

    }
```

Process is probably not the best name for the class, but this is purely a demo.

Also, passing the Page object into another class tight couples that class to the Page object. I would recommend reconsidering your design of the class you're trying to make to not rely on the Page object entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass Page object as one of the parameters to your class methods, this way its elements will be accessible inside the class.

For example if you have a class like:

```
public class CMyDataClass {
   public bool CompareText(System.Web.UI.Page i_oPage) {
      TextBox oTextBox = i_oPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
      return (oTextBox.Text == "My Data");
   }
}
```

You can use it like this from the page:

```
CMyDataClass oMyDataClass = new CMyDataClass();

if (oMyDataClass.CompareText(this)) {
    Response.Write("Ok!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to encapsulate functionality, I guess you best create a class in which you pass the relevant elements to the constructor.

If you are aiming on reuse in other pages, you could create a base page from which you inherit. Another option is to do stuff in a master page that you refer from your pages.

I think a more detailed question is required to give a more detailed answer.